# Mantener argumento en mi widget al utilizar select2 en Django

Tags: python, django, django-forms, select2

Estoy utilizando **Python 2.7** y tengo un problema para obtener un argumento en mi widget al utilizar **select2**.

Al cargar la página el *print* del widget muestra el texto: **Prueba** correctamente, sin embargo al momento de utilizar el campo select2 cada vez que se realiza la petición el *print* es **False**.

En mi ejemplo el argumento **Prueba** necesito que persista aún y cuándo se utiliza el **select2**.

> requirements.txt

```
Django==1.11.12
django-select2==6.3.1
django-widget-tweaks==1.4.2
Jinja2==2.10
```

> views.py

```
def home(request):
    form = Form(nombre="Prueba")
```

> forms.py

```
class Form(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        nombre = kwargs.pop("nombre", False)
        self.widgets['nombre'] = NombreWidget(nombre=nombre)
        super(Form, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

> widgets.py

```
class NombreWidget(ModelSelect2Widget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.nombre = kwargs.pop("nombre", False)
        print(self.nombre)
        super(NombreWidget, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

> home.html

```
{% render_field form.nombre %}
```

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que estas haciendo pop() de `kwargs` y eso hace que se vaya del diccionario.

Help de `pop`:

> pop(...) method of builtins.dict instance
>       D.pop(k[,d]) -> v, remove specified key and return the corresponding value.
>       If key is not found, d is returned if given, otherwise KeyError is raised

La forma de hacerlo sería utilizando `get`:

**forms.py**

```py
class Form(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        nombre = kwargs.get("nombre", False)
        self.widgets['nombre'] = NombreWidget(nombre=nombre)
        super(Form, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

**widgets.py**

```
class NombreWidget(ModelSelect2Widget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.nombre = kwargs.get("nombre", False)
        print(self.nombre)
        super(NombreWidget, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```